# Map of Osaka Castle circa late 1600s

Tags: japan, medieval-japan

Could you help me find a layout of Osaka Castle after it was rebuilt by Tokugawa Hidetada? I've looked all over the web and couldn't find a thing.

Comment: It's not my specialist area, but wasn't it  Tokugawa Hidetada who rebuilt the castle in the 1620s?

Comment: Thank you! Yes. I meant to write after it was destroyed by Ieyasu during the Osaka Summer War.

Answer (score 3):

There are several images of the layout on the Japanese Wikipedia page for Osaka Castle: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E5%9D%82%E5%9F%8E. In the grouping of three images on the right, the top left shows the castle under Toyotomi rule. The top right shows the layout in the "early Edo period."

> [image: oosakajou]
>   https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ja/b/b4/Oosakajou.PNG

There's also a website on the history of the castle with a page describing it during the Tokugawa period at http://www.osakacastle.net/history/haran/tokugawa.htm. You could run the page through Google Translate if you don't read Japanese.